# Bootstrap 4 drop-down active class is not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

active class supposed to change when clicked on a option.

By default i make the option one is active but when i click on option two but active class is still on option one.

```
<div class="dropdown" >
                <div data-toggle="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item active">one</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item">two</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Three</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item">four</a>

                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why you are putting the active class?

Comment: The [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) does not specify that behavior. They only make the dropdown work. What happens when you click is for you to handle.

Comment: there is no javascript in your post. To update class of your html you need to add some javascript that will change your html

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable inputs. I think the only way around is using a javascript with an "onchange" function.

Comment: You can use html select  tag instead of dropdown.